# SpecRun: How to run tests filtering by .feature file

Tags: specflow, specrun

I am trying to run tests using SpecRun. I would like to run them using the .feature file, but so far I have not succeeded :(

I am using this as a filter:

`/filter:testpath:Feature:FeatureFile.feature`

but no tests are run.

How can I do to specify a .feature file in SpecRun?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Documentation for filters are here: http://specflow.org/plus/documentation/Filter/

For your case you need to specify the parameter this way:

```
/filter:testpath:Feature:<FeatureTitle>
```

`<FeatureTitle>` is the title of your feature in the file. Not the file name.

---

Full Disclosure: I am one of the SpecFlow & SpecFlow+ developers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already knew how to run test with the FeatureTitle, but I wanted to know if it was possible to pass the name of the file as an option

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your question. It is currently not possible to filter by filename. But best practice is, that the feature title and file name is the same.

Comment: Thanks anyways. I appreciate you clarified this for me :)